# How can we improve the below line of code?

Tags: c#

Can we improve this line of code

```
if ((l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications.Where(x => x.DeviceType != DeviceType.UnKnown)).Count() > 0)
        {
            //l_Subscription.DeviceTypeID = ((l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications.Where(x => x.DeviceType == DeviceType.Tablet)).Count() > 0)?()
            if ((l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications.Where(x => x.DeviceType == DeviceType.Tablet)).Count() > 0)
                l_Subscription.DeviceTypeID = (int)DeviceType.Tablet;
            else if ((l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications.Where(x => x.DeviceType == DeviceType.Phone)).Count() > 0)
                l_Subscription.DeviceTypeID = (int)DeviceType.Phone;
        }
```

I just tried with the below but not working...Need help

```
int cnt =  DoOperation(l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications, x => x.DeviceType != DeviceType.UnKnown);
       if(cnt > 0)
       {
           int cnt1 =  DoOperation(l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications, x => x.DeviceType == DeviceType.Tablet);
           int cnt2 =  DoOperation(l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications, x => x.DeviceType == DeviceType.Phone);

           if(cnt1 > 0) l_Subscription.DeviceTypeID = (int)DeviceType.Tablet;
           else if (cnt2 > 0) l_Subscription.DeviceTypeID = (int)DeviceType.Phone;           
       }

        private int DoOperation<TKey>(List<l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications> list, Func<l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications, TKey> predicate)
        {        
            int count = 0;
            count = list.Where(predicate).Count();
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: I count 8 lines, not one. What do you want to "improve" about it?

Comment: Any better way to re-write the statment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple improvement would be to replace

```
.Where( predicate ).Count() > 0
```

with

```
.Any( predicate )
```

Oh, and if that is all your code, you can remove the outer if, because both the inner if condition and the inner else if condition imply the outer if condition, giving you:

```
if ((l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications.Any(x => x.DeviceType == DeviceType.Tablet))
    l_Subscription.DeviceTypeID = (int)DeviceType.Tablet;
else if ((l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications.Any(x => x.DeviceType == DeviceType.Phone))
    l_Subscription.DeviceTypeID = (int)DeviceType.Phone;
```

Comment: I just updated the question with the one which i just tried but not working properly...need help..will appreciate if u can help me

Answer (score 0):

***IF*** the Application collection will always contain only a single DeviceType (meaning no mixes of both Tablets and Phones in the same collection) then the above can be shortened to:

```
   l_Subscription.DeviceTypeID = l_Subscription.PackageInfo.Applications.First(x => x.DeviceType == DeviceType.Tablet || x.DeviceType == DeviceType.Phone);
```

Of course only you know whether that is a reasonable assumption for your scenario...